# Is it possible for an EMV-chip enabled card to not generate an ARQC cryptogram?

Tags: emv

During the transaction verification process for EMV, is it a possibility that the card does not successfully generate a valid cryptogram? Would the terminal attempt to send a transaction online, but the card does not answer and transaction ultimately passes?

Comment: While personalizing the card you can set Issuer authentication not supported in AIP

Comment: @Pras Issuer Authentication is a process taking place after online cryptogram has been generated. You won't get to that when ARQC was not generated in the first place. The other thing is that Issuer Authentication can be performed implicitly when card requests IAD in CDOL2. AIP is not really the setting you are looking for, but rather card risk management parameters that are specific to card application spec.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is "No". When terminal requests ARQC, anything else than that shall be resulting in a decline (or termination, but that's just a technicality that feels all the same from the user perspective).

The other is that you should do any kind of homework before posting.

Comment: Is it possible to have a long answer "YES" ?

Comment: @Leva, It's hard to understand what your situation is. Do you have AAC response or rather something like SW=6985? Can you show a log of your transaction? It's possible to have different answer if you simply fall into some CIAC Decline or some other risk management case